# Batch file runs manually but not through Windows 10 Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I really need help on running a `.bat` file from the Task Scheduler.

It runs when ran from location or when `Run` is clicked from Task Scheduler.

It doesnt run on  a schedule when `Run only when user is logged on` / `Run when user is logged on or not`

The user is my local account is also the admin

`.bat` file is stored in `C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc\`, and this is what iI have filled in for the `Program/Script` under `Settings` in `Actions` tab.

I have unchecked all options under `Conditions` tab, (tried checking the `power` options, *still didnt work*).

I would prefer to have this option set :: `Run when user is logged on or not`.

I would like to know what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong with this.

.bat file code is :

```
cd C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc
set ProjectPath=C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
pause
```

Comment: In the 'Start In' field put the filepath C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc\ Then in the Program/Script put just the name of the bat file without the path. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: already tried that, but it didnt work

Comment: Under security options have you tried enabling the 'Run with highest privileges' option?

Comment: The only other thing to try (odd as it may seem) is to toggle the 'Configure for' dropdown setting on the General tab. Try all the selections and see if one works.

Comment: yes its enabled with Run with highest privilges. Also it asks me for password.

Comment: Tried checking with all dropdown options under Configure - still no luck,

Comment: This site is for help with your code issues, if you're not providing code, your question is off topic, _and would have been better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask), where general questions regarding the use of the OS software belong.

Comment: Need to see the script.

Comment: Actually the script runs when " Run when user is logged in" and when Run is manually clicked from task scheduler,  but ti doesnt run ona schedule

Comment: @GinaGina if you are not going to show us your code the users with enough reputation will vote to close your question.

Comment: @Test
 public static void currFetch() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
 }}

Answer (score 0):

This one saved me:

- Make sure "Run with highest privileges" is turned off in your task scheduler settings
- In your bat file, use `pushd \\network_drive_name` as the first line of code
- At the end of your bat file, use `popd \\network_drive_name`